# Redirect both www and non www to https non www

Tags: redirect, nginx

So I am trying this, redirect both http www and non-www to https non www.

But I just noticed that the redirects only work on chrome, on the other they just die after a while trying, can't open page. I think that in chrome works because of past cache, so it is actually not working ... any idea ?

---

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
        return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
        if ($scheme = http) {
                    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
            }

    }



    server {

            listen 443 default_server ssl http2;

            server_name domain.com;
            access_log  off;
            ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/cert_chain.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;
            ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
            ssl_session_timeout 10m;
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;

              if ($allowed_country = no) {
                return 444;
    }

 }
```

This is a curl -i result, seems that there is a redirect ...

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.9.12
Date: Tue, 22 Mar 2016 22:10:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://domain.com/

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.9.12</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `server` blocks to handle the redirection.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com domain.com;
    return 301   https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443   ssl http2;
    server_name  www.domain.com;

    # Add ssl_<*> directives here, if necessary.

    return 301   https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name  domain.com;

    # Add ssl_<*> directives here, if necessary.
    # And other configurations...
}
```